# Need help mapping this data in Java

Tags: java, dictionary

I am having problems mapping this data

```
          1           35
          1           30
          1           20
          2           10
          3           40
          3           25
          3           15
```

I tried using the HashMap but it would only map to the last occurrence of this data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The behavior of `Map` and `HashMap` you describe is the intended behavior, as other commenters note.  What you want is a multimap.  You can roll your own (don't do this-- other commenters suggest maps to lists, but that quickly becomes cumbersome.  If you really want to roll your own, roll your own generic multimap with list/set values and hide the complexity.) or use [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [multimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).  Example:

```
import com.google.common.collect.HashMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.SetMultimap;

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    final SetMultimap<Integer, Integer> foo = HashMultimap.create();
    foo.put( 1,35);
    foo.put(   1,30);
    foo.put(  1,20);
    foo.put(  2,10);
    foo.put(  3,40);
    foo.put(  3,25);
    foo.put(  3,15);
    System.out.println(foo);
  }
```

Output:

> {1=[35, 20, 30], 2=[10], 3=[25, 40,
>   15]}

If you want to access the values, there are a couple of ways depending on what you want to do.  Just calling `get(Integer key)` will return a collection of the values.

Also, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759440/the-guava-library-for-java-what-are-its-most-useful-and-or-hidden-features/3761140#3761140), which cites lots of related goodness in Guava.

Answer (score 6):

[The documentation states](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html):

> public interface **Map**
>   An object that maps keys to values. A
>   map cannot contain duplicate keys;
>   each key can map to at most one value.

Instead, you can associate a list of numbers with each key.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `Map<Long, List<Long>>` (or whatever type you have) to address this problem.

Answer (score 2):

A `Map` only has single value for a key.  You can use the [`Multimap`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) interface from [Guava / Google Collections](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) to store multiple values for a key.

Answer (score 0):

Or create a Pair< F, S > class and put them in a list

List< Pair< Integer, Integer > >