# Hashtable same Key with different value....?

Tags: java, multimap

Is it possible with java that a hashtable can map the same keys to different values? ..  How can I retrieve both value from hashtable...

Comment: Duplicate, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456280/need-help-mapping-this-data-in-java/4456312#4456312

Comment: Got Similar error when using TF 1 ```tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_file(vocabulary_file="vocab_file.txt")```. Error was ```FailedPreconditionError: HashTable has different value for same key.``` The issue was input Vocab_file.txt had duplicate data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you cannot, unless you store the key's value as a list of values.

take a look at google's Multimap: 
http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

Comment: Yes, and a search of SO with tag multimap reveals a lot of insight on this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multimap?sort=votes&pagesize=50

Answer (score 1):

You cant do that, All the keys in the Hash map or Hash Table should be unique.

Else then you need to consider a different Collection