# Why can't I "static import" an "equals" method in Java?

Tags: java, static, import, compiler-errors, equals

I like using this method here:

```
org.apache.commons.lang.ObjectUtils.equals(Object object1, Object object2)
```

The only drawback (compared to Google Guava, for instance), is that I cannot static import the method. I.e. this is useless:

```
import static org.apache.commons.lang.ObjectUtils.equals;
```

... as my Eclipse compiler will not correctly link that method when writing

```
equals(obj1, obj2);
```

The error is:

> The method equals(Object) in the type Object is not applicable for the arguments (..., ...)

Why is that? Is my statically imported method not applicable if there is a method with the same name (but not the same signature) in any of the super types? Is this formally specified in the JLS? <s>Or some Eclipse compiler issue?</s>

**UPDATE**

This doesn't work either:

```
import static org.apache.commons.lang.ObjectUtils.defaultIfNull;

public class Test {
  void test() {
    defaultIfNull(null, null);
    // ^^ compilation error here
  }

  void defaultIfNull() {
  }
}
```

javac error message:

```
Test.java:5: defaultIfNull() in Test cannot be applied to (<nulltype>,<nulltype>)
defaultIfNull(null, null);
    ^
1 error
```

Comment: Have you considered creating your own "utility" class which just delegates to this method?  You could then name it whatever you wanted and them statically import that.

Comment: I've had a look, and I can't find a good description of this in the JLS. I wouldn't be surprised to hear it's there somewhere, of course...

Comment: @tjg184: I don't mind writing `ObjectUtils.equals(a, b)`. This is more of an academic question. I'd like to understand the compiler...

Comment: @JonSkeet: I didn't find anything either, but that's my lack of comprehension for specifications :-). But in the past, I've seen Eclipse compiler bugs of that sort, so it might as well be going in that direction...

Comment: just tested with javac, doesn't compile.

Comment: @MisterSmith: Yes, I've tested the second example too, with javac

Comment: Revised answer of @Dhirendra looks correct. Note also that Guava engineers di change the signature to Objects.equal(o1, o2). THe JDK7 Objects, however, use the equals signature.

Comment: I would like to point out, that the Bounty is for **credible and/or official sources only**. So far there is plenty of speculation but nothing substantial.

Comment: @Stefan: Good move! Let's hope it works

Comment: @Lucas as rightly pointed out by Brice Methods are also referred as members and the compile time error which you are getting is because Object class( top level class) has equals method so you cannot static import equals method in any subclass of Object. as all classes in java are subclass of Object that means we can not static import equals method in java.

Comment: but now the question arises why eclipse is not showing any compile time errors while static importing equals and once you do javac you get compile time errors?  the answer lies is the compiler which eclipse uses, its  An incremental Java compiler. Implemented as an Eclipse builder,  based on technology evolved from VisualAge for Java compiler. So the issue lies with this compiler,  you can refer more about visual age compiler here http://javadude.com/articles/whyvaj.html

Comment: @Dihendra: Neither Eclipse, nor javac report an import error. The error is at the line where `equals(..)` is invoked.

Comment: @LukasEder THe JLS doesn't specify where the error should be raised. Usually compilers report the issue at the ambiguous statement. If your import is never used, then there's no problems.

Comment: @Stefan I think the references to the JLS are kind of credible and official!

Comment: @Stefan (continuing the last comment) Though I have to agree the JLS is rather vague on some precise point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[JLS 15.12.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.1). identifies two reasons,  why a method can be "in scope":

1. "...there is an enclosing type declaration of which that method is a member"
2. "... due to one or more single-static-import ..."

Now two factors contribute to the surprising result:

1. At this point only the name of the method is considered, signatures come later.
2. The two alternatives mentioned above are connected with "otherwise". In the first case we end up looking in the enclosing class of the visible method. In the second case we use the static import.

This "otherwise" implies that the search scope is restricted to only trying either of the two branches.
First we have to decide whether we search an enclosing type or using a static import. Enclosing type has higher priority, we find a method of the correct name (Test.defaultIfNull()), search ends here. When later we find this method to be incompatible, there's no going back to trying the static import.

The situation is not uncommon in JLS, also other issues of method lookup are organized in phases, where a partial match in one phase may prevent finding a better match in a subsequent phase. Fixed-arity vs. variable arity matching is another example of this concept. The effect in all cases is that compilers do not search the entire possible solution space, but after certain decisions have been made entire branches are cut off and never visited.

A rule of thumb can be derived from the above: Overloading can only select among methods of the same type hierarchy, it cannot select between methods of types unrelated by inheritance.

Comment: I know this has been answered a while ago, but (1) the question is still externally referenced, and (2) none of the answers looks correct to me. Only @Brice's comment of the accepted answer is "speculating" in the correct direction.

Comment: Interesting answer, nice connection to the word "otherwise". And welcome to Stack Overflow, Stephan. I suspect, you're this [Stephan Hermann, whom I've been talking to a couple of times?](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=426676) In that case, nice to meet you :) In any case, it's never too late to provide better answers. I've re-read through the other answers, and I agree with your rationale. This makes a lot more sense now

Answer (score 18):

The collision is actually with `Object.equals()`. All classes are inherited from `Object` and therefore have the `Object.equals()` method which leads to this collision.

You're importing by name, not by signature. You actually can't import a static method named `equals` because of this. Or rather, you can import it, but not use it. I do agree that this should work though.

(Made my comments my own answer.)

Comment: Still doesnt make sense. Even if i import by name if there is no conflict the compiler knows based on the signature which method to call. For an example import two static methods with the same name. No problem.

Comment: I agree. Whatever the mechanism is, reading the JLS it seems that it uses the name only. With types it says "If a single-static-import declaration imports a type whose simple name is n, and the compilation unit also declares a top level type (§7.6) whose simple name is n, a compile-time error occurs". So it's no surprise if it works the same with methods.

Comment: I updated my question to show another case. So you're probably right about your reasoning

Comment: @Stefan If one the methods (even with distinct params) is defined in the class (or superclass), and the other is static imported, doesn't work (just tested).

Comment: @Mister Smith I know it doesnt work. The question is why and if it is stated anywhere.  And also you can import a method with the same name from 2 different objects with different signatures without any problem. So the compiler has some knowledge about the signature of the imported method. At this point i see no reason other then because of the internal structure of the compiler you cant do it and not because it makes sense not to allow it.

Answer (score 17):

As per Java Language Specification

> 1. If a single-static-import declaration imports a member whose simple
>          name is n, and the compilation unit also contains a single-type-import
>          declaration that imports a type whose simple name is n, a compile-time
>          error occurs.  (This error occurs even if both declarations refer to
>          the same type, on the grounds that it is confusing to use two different
>          mechanisms to redundantly import the same type.)
> 2. If a single-static-import declaration imports a member whose simple
>           name is n, and the compilation unit also declares a top level type
>           whose simple name is n, a compile-time error occurs.

So in your case its point 2 mentioned above is the reason you are getting compile time error. so even if method signatures are different if there names are same its a compile time error.

static import [JSR](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/jsr/tiger/static-import.html) and [JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#7.5.3)

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong but the code i posted above contradicts 1.

Comment: @Stefan thank's for pointing this. you are right, these three points were there in Java specification request http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/jsr/tiger/static-import.html how ever the final Java language specification doesnot have the first point mentioned in JSR, rest two points are there in JLS.


2nd point and 3rd point can be viewed at the last two lines of http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#7.5.3

i have edited the answer accordingly

Comment: Hmm, this is about members and types, not methods. That's different. Besides, the compile-time error occurs because of the import, not because of the reference to `equals(..)`...

Comment: ... or am I missing something?

Comment: Methods are included in the "member" category, see point 8.1.6 of the Java Language Specification.

Comment: Its neither a conflict between imports(1) nor a conflict with a top level type(2). The error is not on the import itself (which is fine) but the fact, that the compiler seems to be unable to resolve it to the proper method.

Comment: @Stefan this is a top level conflict, i.e the top level class Object.class has the method equals and that is the reason its giving compile time error.  you can verify it by just adding a equal method in your test class which you are calling Foo's and Bar's equal method  

i hope you are not confused by equal/equals here

Comment: @Dhirendra: Please explain why my example from the question using `defaultIfNull()` doesn't work?

Comment: @Dhirendra The problem is, that the import does not generate a compile error. Easily verified by importing but not using the method. And correct me if i am wrong, but a top level type would be only the class not its methods.

Comment: @LukasEder I tried the example with defaultIfNull, it successfully compiles with Java 6.

Comment: @JBert: What version of the javac compiler?

Comment: @LukasEder Oracle's JDK 1.6.0 update 22. The equals thingy still complains though.

Comment: hmm, I have update 20... funny that there should be a difference? Maybe there was a fix related to this?

Comment: Top level type: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/packages.doc.html#26783 . And i actually created a class(for testing) named equal and imported static methods equal with no conflicts at all.

Comment: @LukasEder Ehr, I must have made a mistake... Somehow, the class now fails to compile, maybe I had some in-between source file compiled... However, I believe Dhirendra's answer may still be correct; the JLS doesn't say _which_ compile-time error should occur in case (2).

Comment: @JBert Yes but it says nothing about using the import. And if i dont use it there is no error(just a warning). But if i import both test.Foo and test2.Foo i get an error(Eclipse: The import test2.Foo collides with another import statement) even without using the imports. Thats how i understand the JLS.

Comment: @LukasEder I understand now your points, the JLS indeed seem rather vague, it might have something to do with the MethodName resolution discussed in [§6.5.7.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.5.7.2) and [§15.12](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.12) of the JLS. (end of part1)

Comment: **This is speculation** right now but it seems that _in the first phase of the method invocation determination_ the members of the class (inherited or not) available in the class will always take precedence over the other available Identifier. So, once the class or interface has been determined in the first phase, the compiler doesn't seem to be able to go back in the first phase if this phase or the subsequent one fail to find a matching signature. Thenb it raises an error, javac actually report this: `equals(java.lang.Object) in java.lang.Object cannot be applied to (<nulltype>,<nulltype>)`

Comment: @Brice this is similar to what im suspecting see my 'answer'.

Comment: @Stefan Agreed (you were supposed to be 'atted' in my previous comment but SO didn't let me add several people in the comment)

Comment: Despite the fact that the quoted source is everything but clear on the issue i think this is the best answer we have currently, thats not just based on speculation.

Comment: That's probably the most acceptable answer... Java keeps amazing me at subtle levels...

Answer (score 6):

I did a few tests. First thing I noticed is that you only need one static import statement for multiple methods of the same name.

```
public class EqualsClass {
  public static boolean equals(Object o1, Object o2) {
    return o1 == null ? o2 == null : o1.equals(o2);
  }

  public static boolean equals(Object o1, Object o2, Object o3) {
    return equals(o1, o2) && equals(o2, o3);
  }
}

import static mypackage.EqualsClass.equals;

public class TestClass {
  public static void main() {
    Object o1 = new Object();
    Object o2 = new Object();

    equals(o1, o2); // Compiles - static context

    Object o3 = new Object();

    equals(o1, o2, o3); // No extra static import required
  }
```

Then I noticed that it doesn't work in an instance context:

```
  public void someInstanceMethod() {
    Object o1 = new Object();
    Object o2 = new Object();

    equals(o1, o2); // Does not compile - instance context

    Object o3 = new Object();

    equals(o1, o2, o3); // As expected does not compile
  }

}
```

But then if I clobber the static import with the class's own static method:

```
public static boolean equals(Object o1, Object o2) {
  return EqualsClass.equals(o1, o2); // Compiles
}

public void someInstanceMethod() {
  equals(new Object(), new Object()); // Compiles!!
  equals(new Object(), new Object(), new Object()); // Doesn't compile!
}
```

The fact that it works in a static context makes a reasonable amount of sense to me. However, it appears there is a significant difference between the resolution of a statically imported method and a defined static method of the class.

Summary:

- Methods with the same name as an instance method cannot be accessed when statically imported from an instance context.
- Static methods from the same class with the same name can be accessed from an instance context.
- A static import gives you access to all static methods with the same name from that class despite the signature (parameters and return value).

I'd be interested to see the part of the JLS or a compiler spec that specifies the resolution of static imports by the compiler and how they are clobbered by local methods.

Comment: That's an interesting finding. Unfortunately, up to now I didn't find the JLS specification on that subject...

Comment: Hmm, I think it might be in [the JSR](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/jsr/tiger/static-import.html). If I get time later I'll have a look.

Answer (score 5):

I also combed through JLS3 and couldn't find a definitive answer.

per 15.12.1, first we need to determine the single class where the `equals` method is declared/inherited. Here we have two candidate classes, and the spec doesn't seem to have a rule to resolve the conflict.

We can investigate a comparable problem. A simple type name may refer to both an imported type, or an inherited type (a member type of the super class). Javac picks the latter. This is probably because of the procedure in 6.5.2, which gives imports the lowest priority.

If the same principle applies, the imported `ObjectUtils.equals` should yield to inherited `Object.equals`. Then per 15.12.2.1, there is no `equals` method in `Object` that's potentially applicable to the expression `equals(obj1, obj2)`

Personally, I'd prefer that import has precedence over inheritance, because import is closer. It also stabilizes the meaning of a name. In the current scheme, suppose `Object` doesn't have an `equals` method, the expression `equals(obj1, obj2)` refers to `ObjectUtils.equals`; now suppose `Object` adds the `equals` method, a totally innocent move, suddenly the subclass doesn't compile. An even worse scenario: the new `equals` method has a compatible signature; the subclass still compiles, yet the meaning of the expression silently changes.

Comment: Nice thoughts, especially about `Object` suddenly introducing new methods. That depicts a big flaw in today's implementation of `static imports`!

Comment: +1 i totally agree with your last paragraph. @Lukas i share your opinion about the flaw also.

Comment: @Stefan: But I sincerely wonder whether this is actually a bug. I have checked the JLS again. Especially the part about shadowing: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.3.1. I would have guessed that the static import is somehow shadowed by `Object.equals()`. But there is no explicit mention

Answer (score 3):

This isnt really an answer (just more questions in a way). This is proof that the compiler does import the methods with signature.

```
package test;

public class Foo 
{
    public static void equal(Object o1)
    {
        System.out.println("Foo.equal Object");
    }   

    public static void equal(Integer o1)
    {
        System.out.println("Foo.equal Integer");
    }   
}

package test;

public class Bar 
{
    public static void equal(Number o1)
    {
        System.out.println("Bar.equal Number");
    }   
}

import static test.Foo.equal;
import static test.Bar.equal;

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    equal((Object)null);
    equal((Number)null);
    equal((Integer)null);
}

Output: 
Foo.equal Object
Bar.equal Number
Foo.equal Integer
```

This may also be related. A method in an inner class 'hiding' a static method in the outer class with a different signature.

http://ideone.com/pWUf1

It looks like the compiler has different places where to look for methods and it checks them one by one but only searches by name leading to a premature termination of the search.

Comment: Very nice finding. It really looks related.

Comment: ... in fact, your finding is indeed related, as it's also specified by JLS [15.12.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.1), which refers to the "[comb rule](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5.7.1)". See [Stefan Hermann's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28749909/521799) for details

Answer (score -2):

It's a method collision with java.awt, you need to reference the package like this:

```
 ObjectUtils.equals(a, b);
```

Comment: I have no dependency to `java.awt`. How can this cause a collision?

Comment: The collision is actually with `Object.equals()`. All classes are inherited from `Object` and therefore have the `Object.equals()` method which leads to this collision.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström: I see that this is the collision. I'm asking *why* this is a collision, because the signature is obviously different...

Comment: Because the name is the same. And you're importing by name, not by signature. You actually can't import a static method named `equals` because of this. Or rather, you can import it, but not use it. I do agree that this should work though.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström: Funnily, I can import it. But you're right, that might be the reason. Even if I haven't found it formally written like that in the JLS yet...

Answer (score -5):

Actually I think this is more of an Eclipse issue than any other thing. 
If you are using an overloaded version of equals() that receives two arguments, there should be no collision with the default Object.equals().

There are a couple of tricks in Eclipse that you can use to get it to recognize the static import:

1 - Add the static type to Organize Imports
Go to:

```
Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Organize Imports
```

then click on "New Static", then "Types", then choose your class (in this case org.apache.commons.lang.ObjectUtils)

While still on the Organize Imports panel, deselect the

```
"Do not create imports for types starting with lowercase letter"
```

(do not forget this, it's important)

2 - Add the type to Content Assist
Go to:

```
Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist Favorites
```

then click on "New Type", then choose your class (in this case, again, org.apache.commons.lang.ObjectUtils)

Now with this you should be able to Ctrl+Space anywhere on your method and get the "equals(Object,Object)" method as possible content. If you choose that method, Eclipse should automatically insert the static import for equals.

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you that I've tested with javac and doesn't compile.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had checked these things before asking on Stack Overflow. Specifically, the static import works for the content assist popup (Ctrl+Space). I can see the `ObjectUtils.equals()` method. But the compiler won't like it. See also this answer and discussion for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890853/why-cant-i-static-import-an-equals-method-in-java#7891243

Comment: I had a very similar problem a while ago and this sorted it out. I suppose it doesn't work for every case... Sorry I couldn't help you :S