# How to fully qualify a class whose package name collides with a local member name?

Tags: java, visibility, java-7, jls

OK, here's a very curious Java 7 language puzzle for the JLS specialists out there. The following piece of code won't compile, neither with javac nor with Eclipse:

```
package com.example;

public class X {
    public static X com = new X();

    public void x() {
        System.out.println(com.example.X.com);
        // cannot find symbol  ^^^^^^^
    }
}
```

It appears as though the member `com` completely prevents access to the `com.*` packages from within `X`. This isn't thoroughly applied, however. The following works, for instance:

```
public void x() {
    System.out.println(com.example.X.class);
}
```

My question(s):

- How is this behaviour justified from the JLS?
- How can I work around this issue

Note, this is just a simplification for a real problem in generated code, where full qualification of `com.example.X` is needed and the `com` member cannot be renamed.

**Update**: I think it may actually be a similar problem like this one: [Why can't I "static import" an "equals" method in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7890853/521799)

Comment: Generated code, eh? I know with JAXB I've used binding files to change the package names to avoid similar problems when generating code from schemas and WSDLs. Not sure if that's an option to you.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: Yes, renaming packages is an option. But as I'm the author of the code-generator ([jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org), not JAXB), I'd like to know a bit more :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This is called obscuring (jls-6.4.2).](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.2)

> A simple name may occur in contexts where it may potentially be
>   interpreted as the name of a variable, a type, or a package. In these
>   situations, the rules of §6.5 specify that a variable will be chosen
>   in preference to a type, and that a type will be chosen in preference
>   to a package. **Thus, it is may sometimes be impossible to refer to a
>   visible type or package declaration via its simple name.** We say that
>   such a declaration is obscured.

Comment: Agh, yes, I've had this happen with static importing some `equals` method before: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7890853/521799. You don't happen to know a workaround? :-)

Comment: @LukasEder Change the conflicting names :) With your JAXB or other code generator, it might be possible to configure the naming strategy.

Comment: Yes, but then I'll let the user solve this problem. I'd like to implement a solution in the code generator, through some clever workaround

Comment: @LukasEder If you control the code generator, then the naming strategy might be your best bet, comparing fields/variables/types/packages names.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to impose other names (neither package, nor member names). I just want to be able to somehow refrerence that fully qualified type, if that's possible.

Comment: @LukasEder The bold sentence is key, sadly :(.

Answer (score 1):

Your attribute com.example.X.com is not static so it can't be accessed via your X class in a static way. You can access it only via an instance of X.

More than that, each time you will instanciate an X, it will lead to a new X : I can predict a memory explosion here.

Very bad code :)

Comment: You're right. I've added the `static` keyword, as that is not related to the problem. I just removed it (erroneously) to make the example a bit simpler :-) I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I work around this issue?

Using a fully qualified class name here can be a problem because, in general, package names and variable names both start with lower case letters and thus can collide.  But, you do not need to use a fully qualified class name to gain a reference a class's static member; you can reference it qualified just by the class name.  Since class names should start with an upper case character, they should never collide with a package name or variable.  (And you can import an arbitrary class with its fully qualified class name without issue, because the import statement will never confuse a variable name for a package name.)

```
public void x() {
    // System.out.println(com.example.X.com);
    // cannot find symbol     ^^^^^^^

    System.out.println(X.com);  // Works fine
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this for completness' sake ;) In my situation at the time, this wasn't an option of course as import statements weren't available in this specific situation...

Comment: You're welcome.  This question was linked from a related issued, and it seemed an overlooked solution to the problem.  Pity it wasn't an option for your specific situation.  (And it was a chance to work on my Necromancer / Revival badges.)

Comment: Indeed, those badges will certainly come in handy at some point :)