# Collect property of objects in collection

Tags: java, collections, properties

In C# I can do this:

```
IEnumerable<long> ids = things.select(x => x.Id);
```

In Java I have to do this:

```
Collection<Long> ids = new ArrayList<Long>(things.size());
for(Thing x : things)
   ids.add(x.getId());
```

Have to do this sort of thing quite a lot now and wonder if there is a more generic way to do this in Java. Could create a method to do it, but then I would have to add an interface with the getId method or something like that... which I can't...

Comment: I assume that `things` does not inherit from Collection or an Array.

Comment: Why do you assume that? I loop over `things` using `for`, so have to be either array or iterable at least.

Comment: @Brett Walker a collection of ids is required, not another collection of things

Comment: @Brett I don't want another collection of things, I want a collection of the values of a certain property of things, in this example their ids.

Comment: What do you want to do with that collection of properites. (Aside:- The type of `this` was not stated.) The specific question may offer different solutions when the larger context is considered.

Comment: Type of `this` and what I want with it is pretty irrelevant. Asked for general solutions, not specific ones :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), specifically the [function interface](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html) :

```
public class ThingFunction implements Function<Thing, Long> {
    @Override
    public Long apply(Thing thing) {
        return user.getId();
    }
}
```

and invoked like this (where transform is a static import from [Collections2](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html) of guava:

```
Collection<Long> ids = transform(things, new ThingFunction());
```

Guava has quite a few [other benefits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3759440/106261) too.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/index.html)' BeanUtils and Collections:

```
Collection<Long> ids = CollectionUtils.collect(things,
        new BeanToPropertyValueTransformer("id"));
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Groovy` you would only have to do this:

```
Set ids = things.collect{ aThing -> aThing.Id}
```

That would give you all the `Ids` from all the things in `Things` as a list.

Here is some [info on Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/), and some [differences compared to Java](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Differences+from+Java)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method. It takes a collection, a method (from the reflection api) and a target class. It invokes the method on all members of the collection and returns a List of the results.

```
public <T> Collection<T> select(Collection<? extends Object> input, Method getter, Class<T> targetClazz) {
    ArrayList<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (Object object : input) {
        try {
            Object resultObject = getter.invoke(object, (Object[]) null);
            if (targetClazz.isAssignableFrom(resultObject.getClass())) {
                result.add(targetClazz.cast(resultObject));
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I ignored proper error handling for now. Usage:

```
try {

    Method getId = Thing.class.getMethod("getId", null);
    Collection<Long> result = select(things, getId, Long.class);

} catch (SecurityException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but you can wait for java 8, which will have lambda expression support. Other than that I think Guava is your best option.

Comment: With the speed of Java, that might take a few decades though? :p

Comment: it's on the schedule for october 2012, so it's just behind the corner ;)

Comment: But that doesn't mean I will be able to use it then, hehe. Still on 1.6 in the organization I currently work...

Comment: java 8 lambda expressions 2014 and counting