# How to remove duplicates in following java code?

Tags: java

I have written the following code and i am getting all the duplicates even i have used set.

```
private void validatingpswwithpattern(String password) throws IOException

  {
            List<String[]> list=new ArrayList<String[]>();
            list.add(new String[]{"raj","duvva","sathish"});
            list.add(new String[]{"raj","duvva","sathish"});
            list.add(new String[]{"raj","duvva","sathish"});
            list.add(new String[]{"raj","duvva","sathish"});
            list.add(new String[]{"raj","duvva","sathish"});
            list.add(new String[]{"raj","duvva","sathish"});


            Set<String[]> hs = new HashSet<String[]>();
             hs.addAll(list);
             list.clear();
             list.addAll(hs);
             System.out.println(list);
}
```

Comment: You are adding to the collection an arrays, which are compared by reference. That means all the objects are different, because all have a different references.

Comment: visit following link. it might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/21985571/4944490

Answer (score 6):

Since arrays don't override the default implementation of `hashCode` and `equals` from `Object` class, `HashSet` is useless for eliminating duplicates.

You could use a `TreeSet` and supply a `Comparator<String[]>` that would determine when two `String` arrays are equal.

```
TreeSet<String[]> set = new TreeSet<> (new Comparator<String[]>() {
  public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2)
  {
    // write here logic to determine whether o1<o2 (return -1) or
    //                                       o1>o2 (return 1) or 
    //                                       o1 is equal to o2 (return 0)
  }
});
set.addAll(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do in the following way. If you want to remove duplicate elements, then you can do something in this way.

```
List<String[]> list=new ArrayList<String[]>();
list.add(new String[]{"raj","duvva","sathish"});
list.add(new String[]{"raj","duvva","sathish"});
list.add(new String[]{"raj","duvva","sathish"});
list.add(new String[]{"raj","duvva","sathish"});
list.add(new String[]{"raj","duvva","sathish"});
list.add(new String[]{"raj","duvva","sathish"});

TreeSet<String[]> set = new TreeSet<String[]>(new Comparator<String[]>() {    
  @Override
  public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
    return Arrays.equals(o1, o2)? 0 : 1;
  }
});
set.addAll(list);

list = new ArrayList<String[]>(set);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `HashSet` you need to wrap your `String[]` into a `List` using `Arrays.asList`.